# double loops stuck in forever loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I am trying to loop over my $('.fore-col') and iterate the index position of my api call variables each time incrementing upwards.  Starting at 7 and going up by 8 until at the postion of 40.  When i run this code, it is stuck in a "forever loop" i believe and didn't stop at the index position of 40.  highest count before i pulled the plug was just over 20k.
Any help would be much appreciated!

````
                url: forecastURL,
                method: "GET"
            }).then(function(res) {
                console.log(res);

                $(".fore-col").each(function() {
                    for (let i = 7; i < 40; i + 8) {
                        let date = res.list[i].dt_txt;
                        let icon =
                            "https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" +
                            res.list[i].weather +
                            ".png";

                        let temp = res.list[i].main.temp;
                        let humid = res.list[i].main.humidity;
                        console.log(date, icon, temp, humid);
                    }
                });

    ```
    enter code here
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for (let i = 7; i < 40; i + 8)` should be

`for (let i = 7; i < 40; i = i + 8)`

Comment: Thank you Archie.  I'm brand new and appreciate the help!

Comment: @JohnSasser great it helped! Do close the question by marking it the correct answer :)